# PDO bindValue PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Estou estudando PHP e estou vendo PDO orientado a objeto porem realizei uma conexão já testada, porém o `bindValue` retorna erro na hora da execução, esse erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::bindValue()
>   in C:\wamp64\www\teste\classe.php on line 27

Código:

```html
<?php
 

 class funcionario{

  private $con;
  private $nome;
  private $cnpj;

  public function __construct(){
   require 'conexao.php';
   $this->con = $pdo;
  }

    public function __set($atrib, $value){
          $this->$atrib = $value;
      }
 
      public function __get($atrib){
          return $this->$atrib;
      }

  public function cadastrarFuncionario(){
   $cmd = $this->con;

   $cmd->prepare("INSERT INTO fornecedor(nome, cnpj) VALUES (:nome, :cnpj");
   $cmd->bindValue( ':nome', $this->nome );
   $cmd->bindValue( ':cnpj', $this->cnpj );

   $resultado = $cmd->execute();

   if (resultado){
    echo "Dados armazenados!";
   }else{
    echo "Dados Não Armazenados!";
   }



  }


 }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bindParam() e bindValue() são metodos do PDOStatement que neste contexto é o retorno do prepare. Faça um teste com este modelo que mandei!

```
<?php


    class funcionario{

        private $con;
        private $nome;
        private $cnpj;

        public function __construct(){
            require 'conexao.php';
            $this->con = $pdo;
        }

          public function __set($atrib, $value){
          $this->$atrib = $value;
      }

      public function __get($atrib){
          return $this->$atrib;
      }

        public function cadastrarFuncionario(){
            $cmd = $this->con;

            $st = $cmd->prepare("INSERT INTO fornecedor(nome, cnpj) VALUES (:nome, :cnpj");
            $st->bindValue( ':nome', $this->nome );
            $st->bindValue( ':cnpj', $this->cnpj );

            $resultado = $st->execute();

            if (resultado){
                echo "Dados armazenados!";
            }else{
                echo "Dados Não Armazenados!";
            }



        }


    }

?>
```

Comment: Na realidade o erro é apenas a falta de um parêntese no final da query. É preciso fechar o parêntede do VALUES, dentro das aspas.

Comment: tinha esse erro do PDOStatement e tinha tmb esse problema na query